# Pull up view for React Native

Tags: react-native

I'm looking for a React Native component that works similar to the Maps app in iOS 10, where there is a view that "pulls up" over top of the map, that is either partially visible, pulled all the way up to the top so you can scroll through the content of that view, or pulled down to the bottom so you can interact with the content underneath. Does anyone know if a component like this already exists or if one can be made out of other existing components?

Answer (score 0):

You could try the 'react native sliding up panel'.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-sliding-up-panel